# Dto from multiple string in Entity mapstruct

Tags: java, spring, mapping, dto, mapstruct

I´ve being looking in SO for this question but can´t find an answer.

I would like to know if there is a way to map from multiple Entity´s fields to single DTO but with another mapper and into an encapsulated DTO.

An example:

This is my entity:

```
public class Identification{
    long dbId;
    String id;
    String type;
    String completeName;
    boolean status;
}
```

My DTO:

```
public class PersonEntity{
    String completeName;
    IdentificationEntity identificationEntity;
}

public class IdentificationEntity{
    String documentNumber;
    boolean status;
    String documentType;
}
```

I Created my mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {IdentificationMapper.class})
public interface PersonMapper {



    PersonEntity toPersonEntity(Identification identification);
}
```

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface IdentificationMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "id", target = "documentNumber")
    @Mapping(source = "type", target = "documentType")
    IdentificationEntity toIdentificationEntity(Identification identification);


}
```

but i don't know how to map the **IdentificationEntity** from PersonEntity with a mapper. What I mean is if there is a way without using @AfterMapping, already tried with annotation **uses** and really I don't know if this is posible by **qualifiedBy**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PersonMapper {


    @Mapping(target="identificationEntity", qualifiedBy=IdentificationMapper.class)
    PersonEntity toPersonEntity(Identification identification);
}
```

Please some help with this. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood you would like to use the `IdentificationMapper` to map the `Identification` into `IdentificationEntity`.

You almost got it.

You need to tell MapStruct to map `identification` into the `identificationEntity` from the `PersonEntity`.

E.g.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {IdentificationMapper.class})
public interface PersonMapper {


    @Mapping(target = "identificationEntity", source = "identification")
    PersonEntity toPersonEntity(Identification identification);
}
```

The `IdentificationMapper` stays the same.

Regarding the `qualifiedBy`. That is needed when you want to map some properties in a special way. For example to upper case some strings, but only on those specific properties. There you need to use the MapStruct `@Qualifier` to qualify your methods. You can read more about them in the [Mapping method selection based on qualifiers](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers) from the documentation